# Multiple keyframes are generated with same name in production build(not using css modules)

Tags: reactjs, css-loader, webpack-4

we are not using css modules in our project . when compiling the prod build
multiple keyframes are having same names. how can we tell css-loader to stop mangling keyframes names?. Due to this issue wrong keyframe animation is applied at wrong dom node.

```
"css-loader": "^0.26.0",
"webpack": "^4.10.2",
```

Any suggestion will be really appreciated

Already lodged an issue on css-loader
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/749

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer for other's reference and requirement. So i was not using css-modules in my project and webpack 4 prod build was renaming some keyframes with same name "a" in one scope. How I solved the issue is:

I added postcss-loader has the provision to add cssProcessor option in plugins and loader. For "cssNano" you can pass certain option telling not to rename keyframes names.

```
Install cssnano first

npm install --save-dev cssnano

in your webpack config file. //for my case it was webpack.prod.config.js
const cssNano = require("cssnano")

In your loader add following for postcss-loader
 {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              config: {
                ctx: {
                  cssnano: {
                    reduceIdents: false,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },

And add following for Plugins:
//using optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin for minimification of css
new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(
      {
        cssProcessor: cssNano,
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/,
          discardComments: { removeAll: true },
          reduceIdents: false,
        },
      }
    ),
```

That configuration stopped renaming keframes and animations starts working properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if you are using cssnano version less than 4.0. 
From 4.0 release, cssnano no longer renames animations by default (reduceIdents is turned off by default).

https://cssnano.co/guides/optimisations/

So updating to the latest version of cssnano would automatically fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes can take a custom identifier or a string as a name; the latter is enclosed in quotes. A better fix is to use the string identifier for keyframes: e.g.:

```
@keyframes 'cd-fade-in' {...}
...
animation: 'cd-fade-in'...
```

The names are preserved in the compiled css without changing the optimization parameters in cssnano.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#typedef-keyframes-name